# Estimate of a solution of Schroedinger equation for a free particle

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, schrodinger-operators

Let $\psi(x,t)$ be a solution of the  Schroedinger on the line
$$i\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial t}=-\frac{1}{2m}\frac{\partial^2  \psi}{\partial x^2}.$$
One assumes that $\psi(x,0)$ "behaves well" as $|x|\to \infty$, e.g. square integrable on the line. If necessary one may impose some extra assumptions.

> For a fixed bounded interval $[a,b]$ I would be interested to estimate the behaviour of 
>   $$\int_a^b|\psi(x,t)|^2dx$$
>   when $t\to +\infty$.  The above integral is expected to decay as $t\to +\infty$, and the question is to give a more explicit estimate. Eventually I would like to show that
>   $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}dt\int_a^b|\psi(x,t)|^2dx<\infty.$$

Comment: For large $t$, the [propagator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Basic_examples:_propagator_of_free_particle_and_harmonic_oscillator) is $1 / \sqrt{t}$ times some oscillations, which become slower as $t$ grows. Thus, $\psi$ will generally decay as $1 / \sqrt{t}$.

Comment: But if you apply that say to a smooth function with rapid enough decay, can that improve the estimate?

Comment: No, the decay at large times does not seem to depend on the decay for large $x$. If I am not mistaken, the decay becomes faster if $\psi(x, 0)$ is integrable, and the integral of $\psi(x,0)$ is zero. Similarly, the decay should further improve if additionally higher moments of $\psi(x,0)$ vanish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the free evolution specifically, in relation to [Mateusz's comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346077/estimate-of-a-solution-of-schroedinger-equation-for-a-free-particle#comment866168_346077): on the Fourier side you can write the solution as (for $m = -1/2$; you can rescale/invert time to get other scalings)

$$ \phi(t,x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int e^{it\xi^2} e^{ix\xi} \hat{\phi}_0(\xi) ~\mathrm{d\xi} $$

where $\hat{\phi}_0$ is the Fourier transform of the initial data. Stationary phase tells you that locally uniformly in $y$ you have (notice also that the limit is independent of $y$)

$$ \lim_{t\to\infty} t^{1/2} \phi(t,y) = \frac{e^{i\pi/4}}{\sqrt{2}} \hat{\phi}_0(0) = \frac{e^{i\pi/4}}{2\sqrt{2}} \int \phi_0(x) ~\mathrm{d}x $$

Similarly, you have that if $\hat{\phi}_0(0)$ has vanishing first $k$ derivatives, then locally uniformly

$$ \lim_{t\to\infty} t^{1/2 + k+1} \phi(t,y) \propto \hat{\phi}_0^{(k+1)}(0) \propto \int x^{k+1} \phi_0(x) ~\mathrm{d}x $$

This estimate holds, in particular, for all Schwartz initial data.

Comment: Many thanks. This answers my question. Let me comment that your argument shows that the required integral does converge provided $\hat\phi_0 =0$. This fact is sufficient for the application to scattering theory I am interested in -proof of existence of Moller operators. This is due to the fact that functions satisfying this condition are still dense in $L^2$.

Answer (score 2):

[The evolution of free wave packets](https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.0188) addresses the problem of the late-time spreading of a wave packet $\psi(x,t)$ that at $t=0$ has momentum distribution $\phi(p)$, average position $\bar{x}$, and position variance $\Delta_x$:
$$\psi(x,t)= \sqrt{\frac{m}{ it}}\, \exp \big[\frac{im}{2\hbar t}(x^2-\bar{x}^{2})\big]\phi \big(\frac{m}{t}(x-\bar{x})\big)+\delta \psi$$
$$|\delta \psi|^{2}\leqslant\sqrt{m^{3}/\pi \hbar^{3}t^{3}}\Delta_{x}^{2}.
$$
For $|\delta \psi |$ to be small compared with $\psi$ we require $|\delta \psi |^{2}\ll1/2\Delta_{x}$, which leads to $t\gg (4/\pi)^{1/3}m\Delta_{x}^{2}$.

The large-$t$ decay of the survival probability $\int_a^b |\psi(x,t)|^2\,dx$ may therefore be as slow as $\propto 1/t$, so the integral $\int_0^\infty dt$ may diverge logarithmically. See this example in the cited paper for the case of an initial square wave packet where this slow decay applies:

\begin{equation}
 \psi(x,0)=  \begin{cases} 1/\sqrt{a},   &|x|<a/2 \\ 0,   &|x|\geq a/2.\end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:phiRect}
 \phi(p)=\sqrt{\frac{a}{2\pi \hbar}}\frac{\sin (a p/2\hbar)}{a p/2\hbar}
\end{equation}
and therefore, for $t\gg ma^2 /\hbar$, 
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:appRect}
 \psi(x,t)\approx \sqrt{\frac{a m}{2\pi i\hbar t}}\, \exp \left(\frac{i m x^2 }{ 2\hbar t}\right)\frac{\sin (a m x / 2\hbar t)}{a m x / 2\hbar t}.
\end{equation}
with a logarithmically diverging $\int_0^\infty \int_0^1 |\psi(x,t)|^2\,dxdt$.

---

The above is in response to the OP where the case of zero potential is requested. For the special case that there is an infinitely high potential wall at $x=a$ and a delta-function tunnel barrier at $x=b$, the survival probability has been calculated exactly in [An Exact Solution to the Time-dependent Schrodinger Equation for a Model One-dimensional Potential](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0403177). The survival probability $\int_a^b |\psi(x,t)|^2\,$ decays for large times as $1/t^3$. The paper argues that this power law decay is generic for escape from a potential well.

Comment: I consider a different question: the potential vanishes on the whole line.

Comment: ah, OK, I will modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: I have not understood the details of your answer. This would be interesting but bad news for me.  I am trying to understand the scattering theory in the baby version, on the line. If what you wrote is correct, there will be a problem to define the Moller operators even for compactly supported potential.  I could not find in the literature discussion of scattering theory on the line.

Comment: I have worked out this example from the paper, with an initial square wave packet.

Comment: @MKO: adding potential can actually make things better. The free evolution has a resonance at zero which gives the $1/\sqrt{t}$ decay. The perturbed evolution can break that (in fact, frequently does) and you can get (locally uniformly) $t^{-3/2}$ decay. (I only just learned about this a few months ago and it is still extremely surprising for me.)

Comment: I have some not entirely rigorous/complete notes based on what I learned, in a slightly different context, [here](https://qnlw.info/post/infinite-energy-schrodinger3/).

Comment: @WillieWong --- indeed, that was my original answer, which I deleted because the OP explicitly wanted $V=0$ --- I have now reinserted that text.